# Extract txt file from a .tar.gz with Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to extract only a txt file from a tar.gz file? Because when I'm using `untar`, all files are unzipped. I'm asking because I want to optimize the code. I've tried with this but it's not working:

```
a = untar('C:\docN01.tar.gz', '*.txt')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `untar('C:\docN01.tar.gz')` without that txt

Comment: Also, instead of "it is not working", copy the error message.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. Sorry, I haven't explained the problem so well. I want to extract inside that "tar.gz" only the txt file, not the other files (the others files are images).

Comment: If your operating system or some external tool can do that, you can call it from Matlab using [`system`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/system.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot extract a specific file, as `untar` will extract all of them.
You can however

`filenames = untar('C:\docN01.tar.gz')`

and then loop over the string cell array to find the file that you want, and open it.

Alternatively, you could use `eval`, `dos` or `system` to invoke an external utility such as posix gzip or untar.

By the way, the documentation for [untar](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/untar.html) is your friend.